# Type string is not assignable to string literal

Tags: typescript

I want to be using [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#string-literal-types) from `typescript`. My interface:

```
interface Props {
   size: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
   count: number;
}
```

However I came across two issues:

1. Error on using destruction

If I have my data in object

```
const data = {
  size: 'small',
  count: 36,
};
```

And then when trying to destructure it `<Component {...data}>` I get following error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"small" | "medium" | "large"'
```

2. Using environmental variables

I get exactly same error using environmental variables:

```
size = process.env.SIZE; // while having SIZE = 'small'; in my .env file
```

Can someone help me with advise on how those one can be fixed? Highly appreciated.

Comment: Crowder, yes, good catch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preface: I'd define a type alias for the union, so you can use it in more than one place:

```typescript
type Size = "small" | "medium" | "large";
```

Using that name...

Re #1: The problem is that although you've used `"small"` as the value of `data.size`, it can be overwritten with any other string. Its type is `string`, not `Size` (`"small" | "medium" | "large"`). You could tell TypeScript that it's `"small" | "medium" | "large"`, though, either by defining a type for the object and applying it to the `data` constant:

```typescript
// Inline, or use `type` to define it separately
const data: Props  = {
//          ^^^^^
  size: 'small',
  count: 36, // I've assumed the `number: 36` in the question is a typo
};
```

...or via a type assertion:

```typescript
const data  = {
  size: "small" as Size,
//             ^^^^^^^^
  count: 36,
};
```

Alternatively, if `data` will never change, you can use `as const` to say that:

```typescript
const data  = {
  size: "small",
  count: 36,
} as const;
//^^^^^^^^
```

Re #2, the environment variable could be **anything**, so typically you'd use a type assertion function:

```typescript
function assertValidSize(size: string): size is Size {
    switch (size) {
        case "small":
        case "medium":
        case "large":
            return;
        default:
            throw new Error(`Invalid 'Size' value "${size}"`);
    }
}
```

then:

```typescript
const envSize = process.env.SIZE;
assertValidSize(envSize);
data.size = envSize;
```

There are a few ways to spin that (a type guard function instead of an assertion function, etc.), but that's the basic idea.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Is it possible to make assertion function for environment variable without manually going through cases? Like pick up values from type itself and loop through them?

Not if you start with the type, but you can instead start with a constant array of the valid sizes, then derive the type and the type assertion function (and/or type guard function) based on that constant array:

```typescript
// The valid sizes
const sizes = ["small", "medium", "large"] as const;

// The type for an entry in `sizes`
type Size = typeof sizes[number]; // Ends up being `"small" | "medium" | "large"

// A type assertion function for a valid size
function assertValidSize(size: string): asserts size is Size {
    if (!(sizes as [string, string, string]).includes(size)) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid Size value "${size}"`);
    }
}

// Using it with `process.env.SIZE`:
assertValidSize(process.env.SIZE);
let size: Size = process.env.SIZE;
```

The `as const` on `sizes` tells TypeScript that its contents won't change, which lets TypeScript

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkHsGMGtQC4AsCmoAGAHATjFBnfdUSAIwCsVoEAoAEyoBsBDbNRlBUHPQgLlABvGqFGgUAOwBuA4WPmgAygEkAWgFEB+BNgCWEgOYBuEWIC+NMyZohQAFVSgpzRrrqh8ugF4Ea0SBLaHt4EoAC8oADaAET4ALYujNEANKDRcSh0ugCucSlpLNgGKNEAuqDM+KD+gQjWtg5oCACemGgAZpDYFRLiEjrNoPoYnj5ENC1tSiHhiK0okO3BY5ESuaQo2KVGoLbqEnRV2ZigG-oGGLEJjEmgAD5pGVm50fcFrMXRNDZgAIJzU0q+E2CF0AVA7WyEmoYN6nW6zCcLjcyxQNEh0NB4KBIIAasi6IoQgAKUYoLQ6c4ASgEOOwCCqZKGVSJPiEplEuiWxIAhKSQlVKlFtHpDKkRedxZTDKUqQA6fTQRjZBj4fk+KlU9kKMTIXAAd1AEhQhvU2Fw2GJ6GU0gJ0zZzmVaGiABJBGSzNF0FSTPILBYfqAAKqeQxDLj63TIDA8aAEfByyRSOUqDToPg0OkIfGuQkk2PxxPSFNqdQ+mgcLhkgSstARAuEIvJ1PqIxAA)

Comment: Is it possible to make assertion function for environment variable without manually going through cases? Like pick up values from type itself and loop through them?

Comment: @Alyona - Not starting with the type, no, but there's another way -- I've updated the answer.